# error al buscar información en base de datos: mongodb

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose

Cuando intento buscar en matches los partidos de un equipo cuando es local y visitante la app crashea. La forma en la que intento buscarlo es filtrando en mongo los partidos en los que el nombre del equipo visitante o local sean iguales al del parámetro recibido, osease el equipo.

```
app.get("/equipos/:team", async (req, res) => {
  const teams = await Team.find({});
  const { team } = req.params;
  const teamInfo = await Team.find({ teamName: { $eq: team } });
// Acá es donde crashea
  const matches =  await Match.find({$or: [{home:{$eq: team}},{away: {$eq: team}}]});

  res.render("infoEquipos", { teams: teams, team: team, teamInfo: teamInfo, matches:matches });
});
```

Utilicé este esquema con mongoose:

```
const matchSchema = new Schema(
  {
    video: String,
    home: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    away: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    tournament: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    round: String,
    homeScore: Number,
    awayScore: Number,
    penalties: Boolean,
    penaltiesHome: Number,
    penaltiesAway: Number,
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

El código que compartiste parece estar correctamente estructurado. Sin embargo, el problema podría estar en los datos que se están recibiendo desde el cliente o en la forma en que se están pasando los datos al modelo de mongoose.

Asegúrate de que el valor de team que se está recibiendo como parámetro es un string válido y que coincide exactamente con el nombre del equipo en la base de datos. Además, comprueba que los valores de home y away en el modelo de mongoose coincidan con los valores de team en la base de datos.

Por otro lado, si el problema persiste, podrías intentar manejar el error con un try-catch en lugar de permitir que la aplicación crashee. También puedes usar console.log() para depurar y ver qué valores se están pasando a la consulta en MongoDB. De esta manera, podrás identificar el problema con mayor precisión y tomar medidas para solucionarlo.

```
app.get("/equipos/:team", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const teams = await Team.find({});
    const { team } = req.params;
    const teamInfo = await Team.find({ teamName: { $eq: team } });
    const matches = await Match.find({$or: [{home:{$eq: team}},{away: {$eq: team}}]});
    res.render("infoEquipos", { teams: teams, team: team, teamInfo: teamInfo, matches:matches });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error al obtener los partidos del equipo.");
  }
});
```

En este caso, se utiliza un bloque try para envolver el código que realiza la consulta en MongoDB. Si se produce una excepción, el control se transfiere al bloque catch, que muestra un mensaje de error en la respuesta HTTP.

Además, puedes usar console.log() para imprimir en la consola los valores de las variables utilizadas en la consulta para depurar posibles errores. Por ejemplo:

```
 app.get("/equipos/:team", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const teams = await Team.find({});
    const { team } = req.params;
    console.log("Nombre del equipo:", team);
    const teamInfo = await Team.find({ teamName: { $eq: team } });
    console.log("Información del equipo:", teamInfo);
    const matches = await Match.find({$or: [{home:{$eq: team}},{away: {$eq: team}}]});
    console.log("Partidos:", matches);
    res.render("infoEquipos", { teams: teams, team: team, teamInfo: teamInfo, matches:matches });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Error al obtener los partidos del equipo.");
  }
});
```